# Regex - grabbing all <li> tags

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

Let's say that I have a **string** as so (not HTML-- from backend, I am recieving as string. I just formatted this way to be easier to read the dom tree):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="link1">Link1</a>
        <a href="link2>Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="link3">Link3</a>
        <a href="link4>Link4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get grab inside `li` tags and retrieve as so :

```
[
    [<a href="link1">Link1</a>, <a href="link2>Link2</a>], 
    [<a href="link3">Link3</a>,  <a href="link4>Link4</a>]
]
```

I am assuming you need regex to achieve this (no jQuery).

Comment: You assume wrong. Very unreliable to use regex - especially since your HTML is invalid (missing quotes on some links)

Comment: [Do not use regex for parsing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the string in a div and access the links using DOM methods.
It is NOT recommended to parse HTML with RegEx

```js
var html = `<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="link1">Link1</a>
    <a href="link2">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="link3">Link3</a>
        <a href="link4">Link4</a>
  </li>
</ul>`;

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML=html;

// version 1 - just get all links in the string/div
var linksCollection = div.querySelectorAll("a"); // will have some more stuff in it

// version 2 loop each LI and then each A
var lis = div.querySelectorAll("li"),liArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) { // querySelectorAll is array-like
  var links = lis[i].querySelectorAll("a"), hrefArr=[];
  for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
    hrefArr.push(links[i].outerHTML);
  }
  liArr.push(hrefArr);
}
console.log(linksCollection)
console.log(liArr)
```

Comment: I am receiving as a string, so this is not applicable

Comment: Similar. :). Note that the resulting array is not same as OP needs.

Answer (score -2):

Try below code :-

1. I have given id to ul.
2. After that used query selector to get li of ul.
3. Then used query selector to get anchor tags of li.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var li = list.querySelectorAll("li");
//console.log(li);
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
  var temp = [];
  var anchors = li[i].querySelectorAll("a");
  for(var j = 0; j < anchors.length; j++){
    temp.push(anchors[j].outerHTML);
  }
  result.push(temp);
}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <a href="link1">Link1</a>
        <a href="link2">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="link3">Link3</a>
        <a href="link4">Link4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you got voted down because the lack of string handling - you need to process a string as seen in two other answers on this page